# Nethack server play on android?

Tags: nethack, android

I am looking for efficient ways to play nethack on one of the servers through my Android device. I know it is possible through telnet but I have no experience with that. However,  I tried a couple of telnet programs on my device but wasn't able to play properly.

My preference goes to unnethack but I'll go with anything nethack that plays well. I reckon it's not possible to connect to a server using the Android client - I tried the gui one in the past, and unnethack for a few days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JuiceSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh) is mostly a SSH client, but it also has a telnet option. It's the only telnet client I've found so far that supports color.

Telnet to `nethack.alt.org` if you want to play vanilla, and `un.nethack.nu` if you want to play UnNetHack. A list of other servers can be found [on the wiki](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Server).

Comment: How do I register there? It requires a password but the list sais the opposite.

Comment: @MennoGouw Right after you connect, you should see a menu with `r) Register new user`, so just press `r` and type your desired username and password.

Comment: Right after I connect I get a password window pupup, I cannot type into the telnet console directly.

Comment: @MennoGouw Hmm, I'm not sure what you're talking about. Are you connecting like this? Connections -> Quick Connect -> Telnet -> nethack.alt.org -> OK

Comment: Hmm quick connect work, I created a new telnet connection to un.nethack.nu instead of eu.un.nethack.nu. All set now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "nethack client". Nethack servers work by letting you log in over Telnet and play Nethack on the server, with the game's input read from (and output displayed in) your telnet cient.

If you want to play server-side nethack on Android, your best bet is to find a good telnet client for android. Unfortunately, I don't know of any.

Comment: I hope someone else knows a good client. In the meantime I will try some more telnet programs.